# How do I use Rspec and Capybara to verify that I have no dead links?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm trying to use Rspec and Capybara to verify that generated HTML pages have no dead links. Most (if not all) of the links are to relative HTML pages on the same file system.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
it 'has no broken links' do
  all('a') do |link|
    visit link[:href]
    # 200 is the Ok HTTP response
    page.status.should == 200
  end
end
```

However, this is not generating any syntax errors, but nor is it finding links that actually are broken. I suspect there's something wrong with my syntax, but I don't know whey rspec isn't telling me that.

**Edit to add:** I had a missing `.each`, but fixing that only gets me closer. Here's my code now:

```
  it 'has no dead or broken links' do
    all('a').each do |link|
      address = link[:href]
      if address
        if address.downcase.include?('http')
          visit address
        else
          visit '/' + File.dirname(path) + '/' + address
        end
        # 200 is the Ok HTTP response
        expect(page.status).to eq(200)
      end
    end
  end
```

Using `response.status` yields:

```
undefined local variable or method `response' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fcd1aa8e758>
```

Using `page.status` yields:

```
undefined method `status' for #<Capybara::Session>
```

So, I'm closer now, but I don't know what to check to see if it's loaded.

**2nd edit:**

If I change the expect to be:

```
expect(page.title).to_not be_empty
```

I now get:

```
Capybara::Webkit::NodeNotAttachedError
```

Not sure what that means.

**3rd edit:**

I can also change the expect to be:

```
expect(page.status_code).to eq(0)
```

Testing within irb suggests that 0 is the code I should expect for successful loading of the page. This still results in a `Capybara::Webkit::NodeNotAttachedError` result. If I remove the `visit` logic, then the error goes away, but of course, I'm not testing what I want to then.

Comment: are the specs passing?

Comment: The specs are passing, but I don't know if any 'a' links are being visited.

Answer (score 1):

Rspec's should syntax has been replaced with expect. Try this:

```
 (expect(response.status).to eq(200))
```

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md

Comment: Right before you posted that comment, I found that I can run rspec with the `-w` option, which yields quite a few warnings that are outside my control (circular require in capybara), but also this: "warning: possibly useless use of == in void context" where that corresponds to my poor `should` syntax. Your suggestion did not have this problem, so that's great. However, it also failed to find my dead link.

Comment: So if you were to do `visit explicit_broken_link; expect(response.status).to eq(200)` what does it return? Does it pass?

Comment: I'm not sure how to see individual response values. I run `rspec` and get "." for passed tests and "F" for failed tests. I'll go read some more.

Comment: I meant, if you expect a link to be broken then test only that link to check the response e.g. if you expect '/welcome' or `welcome_path` to be broken just do `visit welcome_path; expect(response.status).to eq(200)`

Comment: `visit 'broken_link'; expect(response.status).to eq(200)` does fail as expected.

Comment: The number of links varies, depending on the page. Anywhere from half a dozen to a couple dozen. I've just updated the question with progress I've made.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Capybara's visit method to find your broken links. Visit will always follow redirects and get to a page (even if its an error page). Instead use rack_tests :get method and look at the response code. This method won't follow redirects, so you can test for 404's etc.